# Difference between "screen size" and "screen density" in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, screen-resolution, screen-size

I have a few questions:

1. What is the *screen size*?
2. What is the *screen density*?
3. What is a **difference** between *screen size* and *screen density*?
4. How I can support different densities and different screen sizes in Android?

I have already read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html), but I was unable to understand the difference between *screen size* and *screen density*.

Answer (score 6):

screen size is about how many pixels you can show on screen.

Density is based on your device real size, if it's small and has a higher resolution, than the density is high cause you show more pixels in less physical space.

```
1.screen size concerns an absolute number of pixels. (check out wikipedia Image Resolution)

2.Density (aka Pixels per inch - PPI) concerns a relative number of pixels per inch. (check out the wikipedia Pixel Density)
```

Answer (score 3):

To put it simple:

- Screen size is the physical size of the screen (whether in inch or cm)
- Screen density is the ratio of how many pixels / area of screen size (that's why the unit is dpi, or *dots per inch*)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, `screen size` refers to the size of the screen.This varies from device to device.`screen density` refers to the amount of pixels in a screen.Both are not independent though as screen size affects screen density.

Answer (score 1):

There are different terms and can't be used interchangeably

**density** = how many pixels appear within a constant area of the display, dots per inch = dpi or ppi(pixels per inch )

**size** = amount of physical space available for displaying an interface, screen's diagonal, inch

**resolution** = number of pixels available in the display, scale-independent pixel = sp

Comment: I have use this [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.screensize ]to measure my screen size this application give me a screen size  720x1280 but you said that screen size unit is "inch"