# Android layout design for small,medium and big screens

Tags: android, layout, size

My app is almost done , but the problem is that it's layout has been designed only for small screens by now
and
I want to make it for other sizes ,too
I mean to use drawables with higher resolutions in bigger screens
how should I manage it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030020/android-layout-design-principles/24030100#24030100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tool [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to generate drawables for different screens.This tool provides many things like drawables for ActionBar, Launcher, Tabs icons etc.

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 0):

You can make different size of images and put them in their respected folder to support multiple screens in android.

If you are using eclipse you can see different types of folders in your drawable which support different screens:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

these are respectively used for high, very high and low screen images. You can get more info at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation for that: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:

36x36 (0.75x) for low-density

48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density

72x72 (1.5x) for high-density

96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density

180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density

Also I recommend "Asset resizer" app for mac, is really useful for get all the sizes from each image.