# small Screen size with high in density? how to develop android app for such devices

Tags: android

How to develop app for small screen size but high in density devices?
In my case , I have asus zenfone2 which has 5.5 screen with 414 ppi density means it is xxhdpi device I think but another phone has 5 inch screen with  441ppi density so is it steel xxhdpi or normal-xxhdpi? I don't know the difference between xxhdpi , normal-xxhdpi,large-xxhdpi. how to develop app for such different screen size?

Comment: Since when, 5" is considered a "small-screen"??

Comment: not like that but compare to 5.5 inch ; its small screen than 5.5

Comment: Still it's xxhdpi. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html.

Comment: @Rotwang then both are xxhdpi devices but results of both are different because in my case with 5.5inch screen size texts are perfect aligned but on 5inch screen they overlap

Comment: Screen sizes and screen densities are very different concepts. Which is why you should use dps and sps instead of pixels.

Comment: yes, but I don't know why this happening ; also I have heard of these concepts like normal-xxhdpi  and xxhdpi . I don't know much about them .

Comment: That's for dealing with tablets. Which can have different combinations of screen sizes and densities than normally found od phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with specifics screens size i recommend using as much as you can the attribute `layout_weight` in your views and view group. It will compute the size of your view depending on your screen size. But you have to know that if you have deep view's hierarchy the time of processing vue will raise exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

First 5.5 is not considered a small screen.
Then lets make the difference between size and density

> Screen size is the physical size of the screen (whether in inch or cm.
>   Screen density is the ratio of how many pixels / area of screen size
>   (that's why the unit is dpi, or dots per inch)

I can give you some directions for having same results on different screen sizes.

**First for the outer layouts.**

- Wrap root layouts **Scroll view** or **Nested scroll view** with **Coordinator layout**. It will allow scrolling to the bottom of the page when a screen is not enough.
- Use **Collapsing** for the **Coordinator layout** with the scroll views or nested scroll views. It will collapse the parts of the UI that are not needed when the user scrolls.
- **FABs** have great animations for hiding and showing when not needed and they work like charm with the coordinator layout. You can customize their behavior a lot.
- You can also use **PercentageRelativeLayout** and the normal **RelativeLayout** or **LinearLayout** with the **weight** property instead of absolute layouts. It is easy to create responsive design with them

**For the inner views**

- Use wrap_content, match_parent, or dp units when specifying dimensions in an XML layout file. Except for defining text sizes: sp (scaling depends on user setting).
- Do not use hard-coded pixel values in your application code.
- Supply alternative bitmap drawables for different screen densities.
- Provide different sizes for icons

You can read more about the collapsing views [here](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/).
And more about screen sizes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397030/difference-between-screen-size-and-screen-density-in-android).

Comment: I am not saying 5.5 inch or 5inch screens are small I am saying that as compared to 5.5 inch screen 5 inch screen is small and that phone has high density 441ppi and my 5.5 inch phone has 414 ppi